Want to get call history on android app. But Playstore rejecting app.(kotlin or java)
I am developing an app that retrieves call history to send WhatsApp messages to specific numbers. However, Google Play Store keeps rejecting the app, citing that it needs to be a default dialer app or assistant handler app to access call history. While my app is not a dialer app, I am willing to make it a default dialer if there’s no other option.
Here’s what I have tried so far:
1. Attempt to Set the App as Default Dialer
I used the following code to show the "Set Default Dialer" dialog:
defaultDialerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Default dialer set successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to set as default dialer. ${result.resultCode}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

val setDefaultDialerButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.set_default_dialer_button)
setDefaultDialerButton.setOnClickListener {
    val telecomManager = getSystemService(TELECOM_SERVICE) as TelecomManager
    if (telecomManager.defaultDialerPackage != packageName) {
        val intent = Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER).apply {
            putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName)
        }
        defaultDialerLauncher.launch(intent)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Already set as default dialer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

However, the dialog to set the app as the default dialer does not appear.
2. Using RoleManager for Default Dialer Role
Since my app targets Android Q and above, I also tried using RoleManager:
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    val roleManager = getSystemService(Context.ROLE_SERVICE) as RoleManager
    if (roleManager.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER)) {
        val intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER)
        intentLauncher.launch(intent)
    }
}

Even with this approach, no dialog appears, and the app is not set as the default dialer.
Manifest Changes
I have added the necessary permissions and intent filters in my AndroidManifest.xml file:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>

My Requirement
My app is not a true dialler app; I only need access to call history. However, if making it a default dialler is the only way to comply with Google Play policies, I am open to implementing that functionality.
How can I successfully make my app the default dialler? If there’s an alternative approach to access call history without becoming a default dialler, I’d appreciate guidance on that as well.

I don't know exactly what your app should do however I would suggest checking this page about getting call logs. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10208820?hl=en&visit_id=638711590008224756-673668480&rd=1#zippy=
